# Collection about short stories including very short ones

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I first apologize for the lack of details: I read this collection nearly 30 years ago.

I remember only a very few details about it:

- Stories were of various size but at least include a few very short ones
- They were mainly (only?) SF stories
- They were "smart" stories, whose plot was usually the reason why the story was short.
- I remember one story that does exactly match the previous fact (I think it was only 1 or 2 sentences short) : *Aliens arrived near earth, saw a sign that said "polluted planet", and decided to fly back home* (sounds like that)
- I read it in a French version. The cover might have been light blue (but I am unsure)

This may match a lot of collections of SF short stories, but I hope the only one I remember will help find the one I am looking for!

Comment: Wow, there were a LOT of those ultra-short story collections.  One I recall was *50 Extremely S(hort)F(iction) Stories* -- every story in the chapbook limited to fifty words.

Comment: @ZeissIkon So the entire publication was <2500 words?  That doesn't sound like terrifically good value. :)

Comment: @ZeissIkon It could be. The few first chapters available I read sound quite familiar... but I read that much SF at that time that I think many SF stories sound familiar to me :)

Comment: @DavidW It was a chapbook, in the days before ebooks.  Sold for, IIRC, $2 or similar.  Might have been two stories on a page.  Just a little staple-bound booklet, barely more than a pamphlet.